# Issue about accessing a click function tied to dynatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatable

I am trying to add a click function that does a check of values on a `dynatable` that I am creating when they move from page to page. It is accessed based on the class `dynatable-page-link` that exists on the Pagination section of the table (Prev, page numbers, Next for example).  here is the function call:

```
$(".dynatable-page-link").click(function()
```

I have tried many different places to put this with mixed results.  I had it separate stand alone in my `JSP` and did not work. I looked at other questions and it mentions that it should be included in:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
```

with no success. At this time I don't have a document click function. I added:

```
$(document).click(function () {
```

and it works but is inconsistent.  Is there a reason why I can't get this to work as a stand alone function or inside the document part?

Thanks

Comment: What about `$(document).on('click', '.dynatable-page-link', function() {});`?

Comment: That worked great.  Thanks a lot.  I wish I knew why though.